# Is it possible to trigger an audible alarm when certain conditions are met after the app has completely closed?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, localnotification, flutter-local-notification

I want to receive an alarm that sounds when certain conditions are met during reception with the api even if the app is completely terminated using flutter_local_notification and workmanager in flutter .but, the trigger does not occur when the api receive is long in workmanager.

```
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) async {
       while(conditions are not satisfied)
        {
        receiving api~~~~~~~
        }
        NotificationService().showNotification(some parameter);
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}
```